# Prove or counter-example $X= \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{A}= \lbrace A \subset \mathbb{R} \: | \: A \: \mbox{is bounded in} \:A \rbrace$ is an algebra.

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory

Let $X= \mathbb{R}$, $\mathcal{A}= \lbrace A \subset \mathbb{R} \: | \: A \: \mbox{is bounded in} \:A \rbrace$. Prove $\mathcal{A}$ is a ring but is not $\sigma$-ring, also I was asked to prove $\mathcal{A}$ is algebra or give counterexample it is not.

To prove $\mathcal{A}$ is a ring I only need to prove that if $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$, then $A-B \in \mathcal{A}$ and $A \cup B$ is in $\mathcal{A}$. No trouble proving this as for $A \cup B$ I take the lower bound to be the minimum of the lower bounds of $A$ and $B$, the same for the upper bound.

As $\mathbb{R}$ is not bounded, $\mathbb{R}$ is not in $\mathcal{A}$ so $A$ is not a $\sigma$-algebra.

In order to prove $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebra I should take $\lbrace A_{i}\rbrace_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ where each $A_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$ and prove $\bigcup_{i \in \mathbb{N}} A_{i} \in \mathcal{A}$, but I dont know how to prove this as Im not sure if my idea for finite unions works here. Also I cannot find a counterexample. Any help will be apreciated.

Comment: What does "A is bounded in A" mean?

Comment: An algebra also has to contain $\mathbb R$, hence $\mathcal A$ is neither an algebra nor a $\sigma$-algebra. Also, an algebra only needs to be closed under *finite* unions, so I don't see why you are considering countable unions in your last paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

{ [-n n] : n in N } is a countable collection of bounded sets whose union is not bounded.

Answer (score 0):

An algebra is closed under complementation. Since $(0,1)$ is bounded and its complement is not bounded it follows that $\mathcal A$ is not an algebra.

Also an algebra has to contain the entire space.

Defintion of algebra does not involve countable unions at all, so you are on the wrong track.